# How to add support for LFS (or alternative) in Gitolite?

Tags: git, gitolite

We have two projects which have to store huge blobs and I would like to add support for LFS (or an alternative) in my Gitolite server.

I have found two projects on github which allow for that:

https://github.com/HimaJyun/gitolite-lfs/tree/master/docs/Apache

and

https://github.com/ddanier/gitolite-git-lfs

Both of the projects are not supported anymore by the authors.

I've tried searching for some other ways but I have found none, maybe I'm just not searching right.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is from almost a year ago, but I'm answering anyway).

I personally use [`git-fat`](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat) with gitolite all the time. There's nothing special that you have to do to get it working with gitolite, but you do need to have somewhere, e.g. a vps, to which the files need to be rsynced (see the `readme` in the Github site). A closely related alternative to `git-fat` is [`git-jam`](https://github.com/tiesselune/git-jam). The `readme` of on its Github page provides details of use with gitolite.